# Portable Ubuntu can't see SSD

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, ssd, portable

My laptop has HDD and SSD installed (HDD replaced optical drive). OS Windows is installed on SSD. But something wrong has happened and I need to boot from USB in order to save some files from SSD.

But when booting from USB with installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it I can not see my SSD drive. All HDD partitions are listed as normal.

I've tried `fdisk -l`, `lsblk` to view missed drive but with no luck.

UPDATE:
I can see that drive if I choose "`Install Ubuntu...`".

Answer (score 1):

Oh, got it.
I've removed my SSD from BIOS boot priorities queue and now I can see it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome, you answered your own question. Thumbs up!